# Does uninstalling Custom Module Builder Extension affects the custom created modules

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

We are using vTiger CRM with its Extension Pack from VTExpers, Inc.

We used the Custom Module Builder Extension to Custom Modules Several times, now we want to Uinstall the extension.

My Question is:

What will happen to the Custom Created Modules, which have been created through this Extension, will they disappear as well, or they will remain Active in the CRM?

I want to keep the Custom Modules and remove (uninstall) the Extension it self.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, created modules will be there

Answer (score 0):

They remain in your crm but your custom modules will not work after uninstalling Custom Module Builder

Simply modify YourCustomModuleName_Module_Model class and remove isActive method from class. you can find this class in the following path:

```
modules/YourCustomModuleName/models/Module.php
```

Answer (score -2):

The modules will be there, beware as VT Experts uses ION Cube to encrypt most of their extensions so you have no idea what the code is doing.